# Way to use the INDIRECT function on an array to reference multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a relatively new Excel user that is working in a book with several sheets. On the first and main sheet, I have a table which, among other things, includes the names of all of the other sheets (cells `$A$4:$A$20` referenced below). In each of the other sheets, there are long columns that will potentially be filled with text items (the cells `$G$5:$G$104` in every sheet). I want to create a formula that, along with some other things, looks at the cell above it (`D5`), searches every sheet for the location of that cell, and then displays the cell below it. If the INDIRECT function could handle arrays, searching every sheet would be relatively simple: I believe I could use the function

`SUMPRODUCT(--(D5=INDIRECT("'"&$A$4:$A$20&"'!$G$5:$G$104")))`

inside of my larger formula to search for the item in question, and then use

`INDEX('Sheet Name'!$G$5:$G$104, MATCH(D5, 'Sheet Name'!$G$5:$G$104, 0)+1, 1)`

to display the next item down in the column. Is there a way for me to use the INDIRECT function to get this to work, or at least a way to avoid nesting a whole lot of IF functions? I've referenced the other articles on this site about the INDIRECT function; one suggests using an INDEX function, but that question involves using INDIRECT to reference cells that contain other cell names rather than just sheet names, and I don't believe it applies here.

Comment: Lookup 3D COUNTIFS.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, it worked! For posterity, I slightly modified the SUMPRODUCT function I mentioned above to read `SUMPRODUCT(--COUNTIF(INDIRECT"'"&$A$4:$A$20&"'!$G$5:$G$104"), "=" & D5))` . This returns the correct number of times the item has been listed throughout the rest of these columns in the workbook. I found the info I needed from this fifteen-year-old forum post: [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/why-am-i-getting-this-error-countif-with-3d-reference.224433/)